# In Pandas, creating a new data frame using data filtered by a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

So, I've looked around quite a bit and I haven't been able to find an answer to this problem. I apologize if it is indeed out there.

I have a DF that looks like this:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana','orange'], 
                  'Units': [2,4,6,5,4,3]})
```

I also have a list of lists like this:

```
b = [['apple', 'banana'],['orange']]
```

The goal is to group apple and banana in to 1 column and orange in to another with their respective units summed. The variable in the column will show up as the first item in the sublist. (no sublist will have duplicates).

Here's what I want the output df to look like:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['apple', 'orange'],
               'Units': [15, 9]})
```

Here's where I am right now:

```
for fruit in a['Name']:
for sublist in b:
    if fruit in sublist:
        pd.concat([XYZ,
                   pd.DataFrame({'Name': sublist[0], 'Units': a[a.Name == fruit]['Units'].sum(), index=[0})], 
                  axis=1)
```

XYZ is an empty data frame with columns= Name and Units that I am trying to populate with the results. I don't really understand how to create a data frame when the **fruit is in sublist** along with the sum of it's Units.

Any thoughts? :D

**Edit:** sublists can be anywhere from 1 to 300 items. The code here is just a MWE of a much larger data wrangling problem. Apologies for not mentioning this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pd.Series.isin` and boolean indexing:

```
pd.DataFrame([(l[0], a.Units[a.Name.isin(l)].sum()) for l in b], columns=['Name', 'Units'])
     Name  Units
0   apple     15
1  orange      9
```

Comment: I'm not at home to test this out, but I feel like this might be what I'm looking for. I messed around with isin() for a while but couldn't get it to work properly. I'll select this as the desired solution once I've tested it. I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: @AbdullahShah Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can do this in one line:

```
sum_a = a.replace({"banana": "apple"}).groupby("Name", as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: That is a very clever solution, one I did not think of. However, it would not work in this scenario as the list of lists is huge in reality, as is the Name column in a. This is why I am iterating over the sublists to check if a.Name is inside the sublist. I should have probably mentioned that, that's my bad.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, it is better re-create your object , rather than change the original df , since `replace` still losing the information about `apple` , since you replace apple to banana.So the out put will only contain the information about  `apple`  or `banana`

```
d={','.join(x):a.loc[a.Name.isin(x),'Units'].sum() for x in b }
pd.Series(d)
apple,banana    15 # here you do not losing the information of each items in the list 
orange           9
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I really like your solution and I'm going to save it somewhere. However, in this use case, losing that information for either apple or banana is by design and it serves a different purpose

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to make a function which returns both the name and sum value.

```
from operator import itemgetter

first = itemgetter(0)

def make_rows(cols, df):
    for col in cols:
        name = first(col)
        val = df.loc[df.Name.str.contains('|'.join(col), regex=True), 'Units'].sum()
        yield name, val

df1 = pd.DataFrame(make_rows(b, a), columns=a.columns)

print(df1)

     Name  Units
0   apple     15
1  orange      9
```

Additionally like this as well:

```
from functools import partial

def make_rows(df, col):
    name = first(col)
    val = df.loc[df.Name.str.contains('|'.join(col), regex=True), 'Units'].sum()
    return name, val

p = partial(make_rows, a)

pd.DataFrame(list(map(p, b)), columns=a.columns)

     Name  Units
0   apple     15
1  orange      9
```

Comment: This looks like slick code and I'll definitely play around with it. Would adding a function slow the performance when compared to Chris's answer when scaled up? (just curious)

Comment: I think this would scale well given the fact that it yields values and doesn’t hold much in memory, why don’t you test it out on larger data yourself and see